# Microsoft Word - How do you change figure 1 caption to figure A.1 for the appendix?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to copy a bunch of figures from one Word document into another to be an appendix.  I want the figure numbers to change to A.1 instead of 1.

1. How do I do this?
2. Is there an easy way to change multiple figures to this format?

i.e.

- Figure 1 -> Figure A.1
- Figure 2 -> Figure A.2
- etc

Comment: Are you using automatic figure numbering feature?

Comment: How do you use this?  Truthfully, I am not sure if I am using it or not.

Comment: When you right-click a figure, a popup menu appears. If you select the "Insert Caption" item and click OK, the figure will be numbered automatically, so if you insert other figures before it, the number will increase (sometimes you will need to press `Ctrl-A`, `F9` to update the numbers).

Comment: Oh, yes I am using automatic figure numbering.

Comment: Do you use automatic numbering of headings? Are appendices also numbered automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That succeeded for me too, however, I was searching for a method to put those auto captions in the text, with their auto numbering. In other words, you created an image with a caption, and want to refer to that caption/image in the text.

the method I found was: **Cross-reference**, and with that you can automatically change the numbers of the pictures and of the numbers in the text refering to the captions.